# Error while loading wp-load.php with a cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

i have a folder in the root of wordpress called custom_script with inside a cron_gare.php file
Then i set up a cron that execute this file every hour, but the cron is giving me an error. Looking at the logs i can read:

```
## OVH ## END - 2019-03-04 16:34:04.350811 exitcode: 255
[2019-03-04 18:34:04] ## OVH ## START - 2019-03-04 18:34:04.066685     executing: /usr/local/php7.1/bin/php /homez.2020/alermiitap/www/custom_script/cron_gare.php 
[2019-03-04 18:34:04] 
[2019-03-04 18:34:04] Warning: require_once(../wp-load.php): failed to     open stream: No such file or directory in /home/alermiitap/www/custom_script/cron_gare.php on line 4
[2019-03-04 18:34:04] 
[2019-03-04 18:34:04] Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7.1/lib/php') in /home/alermiitap/www/custom_script/cron_gare.php on line 4
```

Now i'm looking into the cron_gare.php file, that's how i call the wp-load.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once("../wp-load.php");
```

then there is the custom function i need.

Now, if i put into the browser all the url mywebsite.com/custom_script/cron_gare.php the function is working well, no error displayed.

When i try to call it with the cron, the cron log shows me that errors, and the function doesn't start.
Is there any error in the syntax?

Thank you

**SOLVED** - as suggested, the cron job was executed starting from another folder.
I used as suggested, chdir to the new starting folder, then call the wp-load
    chdir('www');
    require_once("wp-load.php");

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that your cron job is using the same PHP ini file as the web server and that it is starting in the correct directory. Based on the error you are getting it looks like both of those things are incorrect.

Comment: cron job is scheduled on the web server cpanel that is hosting the website, the path is correct of the cron_gare.php (otherwise i will not see that error) and also the language selected is php 7.1 that is the same of the php version of the running website.

Comment: You didn't read my comment closely enough. Running something via cron does not necessarily mean that PHP will be using the same ini file that is used when running through the web server. Also, just because your job starts and emits an error does not mean that it is starting in the correct directory. It only means that you correctly told cron where the code you want to run resides.

Comment: Yeah sorry i red that, but I pretty don't know what it means. The only things i know is that the cron is setup where the website is hosting, that's it. i don't know what the cron use and i don't think i can see that. It's a shared hosting, should i ask to the provider?

Comment: In your cron job make a call to `phpinfo();` and send the output to a file so you can see both what directory is it running in/from and what ini file it is using.

Comment: Ok so i created a test.php file and inside it there is this code:

    ob_start();
    phpinfo();
    $info = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
 
    $fp = fopen("phpinfo.html", "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $info);
    fclose($fp);

now what you want to know exactly from the output file? which rows?

Comment: Ok now i have the output file generated from the cron.
The strange thing is that if i run the test.php manually into the browser, output file is created in the same directory.
Now that test.php was run through the cron, the output file is in the first first directory i see when i connect via ftp (outside the www folder)

Comment: Hopefully you are realizing where the problem is. Where something "runs" from cron is NOT the same as when "run" from a browser. You may need/want to use `chdir` in your cron job to get the output where you want/need it.

Comment: Yes, i'm realizing that i don't need to scale directory when calling wp-load.php with the ../ but i need to get into subdirectory to load it.
I'm trying giving the path starting from outside the www directory, if this does not work i can debug with the chdir.
Thank you man

Comment: When you've fixed that if you are still having issues check which PHP is being used by the cron job. It will be in the `phpinfo` output.

Comment: PHP used is
    PHP Version => 7.1.25
so i guess it's the one i set up in the cron job panel, when asked for what language to use.
I would like to rate your answer, but i don't know how to do